# How can i align content left and right into the listview in android?

Tags: android

[image]

[image]

code:

```
{

private ListView l1;
Dbhelper mydb;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
                            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    setContentView(R.layout.e_view);
    l1 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    mydb = new Dbhelper(this);



    ArrayList<Map<String, String>> list = mydb.getAllexps();

    String[] from = { "name", "purpose" };
    int[] to = { android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2 };

    SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, list,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, from, to);


    //adding it to the list view.

    l1.setAdapter(adapter);

    l1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
        long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            int id_To_Search = arg2 + 1;
            Bundle dataBundle = new Bundle();
            dataBundle.putInt("id", id_To_Search);
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Ex_add.class);
            intent.putExtras(dataBundle);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        });

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
}
```

plz help me out

I need to display amount right side of the list and other things to left side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U need to create custom Listview

refere this link and u will get idea what i m telling u ;)

http://androidexample.com/How_To_Create_A_Custom_Listview_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=67&aaid=92

Answer (score 0):

In the following line you are using android's default list item layout `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2`.

```
SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, list,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, from, to);
```

Instead of using this default layout you can define your own custom layout by putting a XML file into your layout folder. In this custom layout file you can align the content as your need.

Answer (score -1):

you should use this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/pop_up_child_container_topview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="100" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="50" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/pop_up_child_inventoryno_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:text="@string/str_fullhistory_popup_child_inv_no"
            android:textSize="@dimen/list_title_textsize" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/pop_up_child_inventoryno_tv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/pop_up_child_inventoryno_title"
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:text="30vuasou3209"
            android:textSize="@dimen/subtext_textsize" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:gravity="right" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/pop_up_child_quantity_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:text="@string/str_fullhistory_popup_child_qty"
            android:textSize="@dimen/list_title_textsize" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/pop_up_child_quantity_tv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/pop_up_child_quantity_title"
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:text="30vuasou3209"
            android:textSize="@dimen/subtext_textsize" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<View
    android:id="@+id/popup_child_seperator"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/pop_up_child_container_topview"
    android:background="@color/fleet_guard_seperator_grey" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/pop_up_child_container_balance"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/popup_child_seperator"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:weightSum="100" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="50" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:gravity="right" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/pop_up_child_balance_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/pop_up_child_balance_tv"
            android:text="@string/str_fullhistory_popup_child_balance"
            android:textSize="@dimen/list_title_textsize" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/pop_up_child_balance_tv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:text="12"
            android:textSize="@dimen/list_title_textsize" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Now that is single cell xml sample for you to align the text on the right hand side.

Answer (score -2):

Hi Om please use linearlayout with horizontal and add textview and set custom xml file to your adapter